# connect-mongo causing MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, keystonejs, connect-mongo

I'm using connect-mongo to store session.

Sometimes I'm getting :

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

I have a relatively large site that uses mongoDB with replications.

I tried to clear the session document and this appear again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may be a known issue happened on sessionstore:

https://github.com/adrai/sessionstore/issues/43

Comment: Issue link for mentioned package connect-mongo: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/issues/287

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even the uuidv4 workaround didn't work for me.
In the end, I moved from 'connect-mongo' to '[connect-mongodb-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongodb-session)'.

You just have to change the configuration store with the original MongoDB URI, and everything works like a charm.

I suspect the 'connect-mongo' is not supported anymore: it has been a while since the last update on github.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem i change the session id that generated from 'express session' by the following code:

```
var uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return uuidv4() 
  }

}))
```